# Hide day from datepicker

Tags: android

I need hide the day field from a datepicker, I found this method, but the problems is in the version of Android 2.3.3, works fine, but in the version 4x of android not hides the day field. I guess is the library  "*java.lang.reflect.Field*" is obsolete , but I'm not sure of this.

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793811/how-to-display-year-only-in-date-picker-in-android)

may be going on here?

```
final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(this);                                     
                LLayout.addView(datePicker);

                hideDayField(datePicker, "mDayPicker");


    private void hideDayField(DatePicker datePicker, String name) {
    try {
        java.lang.reflect.Field field = DatePicker.class.getDeclaredField(name);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        View fieldInstance = (View) field.get(datePicker);
        fieldInstance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That approach you're taking uses reflection to mess with some hidden fields of the `DatePicker`-class. The problem with this is, that when the internals of a class change (e.g. the name of the field you're getting changed) this won't work anymore.

See [the Docs on Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

In your linked question, there are some other options provided, which might be better suited.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar hiding the day and the month, found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401915/hide-year-field-in-android-datepicker)

```
try {
    java.lang.reflect.Field[] f = picker.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (java.lang.reflect.Field field : f) {
        if (field.getName().equals("mDayPicker") || field.getName().equals("mDaySpinner")
           || field.getName().equals("mMonthPicker") || field.getName().equals("mMonthSpinner")) {
           field.setAccessible(true);
           Object dmPicker = new Object();
           dmPicker = field.get(picker);
           ((View) dmPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is giving me a NullPointer exception.