# AlertDialog with DatePicker

Tags: android, datepicker, android-alertdialog

My idea is to use an AlertDialog and set to it a a DatePicker.
My code is:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    DatePicker picker = new DatePicker(this);
    picker.setCalendarViewShown(false);

    builder.setTitle("Create Year");
    builder.setView(picker);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Set", null);

    builder.show();
```

it works, but my question is: how can i **have the listeners on the set and cancel button**?
About the set button i would like to have the listener and (of course) **get the date of the user (his date selection)**

I want also **show just the year** so i want to hide the day and month data.

Comment: for getting the value use picker. e.g. picker.getDayOfMonth

Answer (score 7):

You can use `setPositiveButton`, like this :

```
dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    //do something         
  }
});
```

The same for `setNegativeButton`.

> I want also show just the year so i want to hide the day and month
>   data

See this, use the 1st answer :

[Hide Year field in Android DatePicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401915/hide-year-field-in-android-datepicker)

Comment: Perfect, thank you. now when the user click set, i'm in the method of the listener but how can i get his date? (the date that he has selected?)

Comment: @GiovanniFar No offense, but its how SO work, 1 answer for 1 question..you even already asked 2 questions. Better for you to create another question for future problems

Comment: usually happen that i get down vote because they say: u can merge all in 1 question, now isnt good because i have split the questions... :roll: in everycase thank u so much