# Android - Unable to display a DatePicker from within an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog, android-datepicker

I have an `AlertDialog` which includes a button to initiate a `DatePicker`. Is it possible to accomplish this within a dialog and if so how would I go about it?

I have searched Google and several posts on SO but have been unable to find information on accomplishing a `DatePicker` within an `Alert Dialog`.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834831/alertdialog-with-datepicker

Comment: I attempted that solution myself. The problem that I face is that the solution there is for JUST a DatePicker. Here is a screenshot of the AlertDialog I am referring to. http://imgur.com/jPlmKw1 where I want to open up the DatePicker clicking on "Set Date" button and then, once selected, go back to the AlertDialog shown.

Comment: So the set date button, you want that to open up another dialog? or display a datepicker in that current dialog?

Comment: Ideally, I would like the DatePicker to open up within the same dialog then once a date is selected return to the edit dialog (this is because when "Update" is clicked, the date will be updated in the parent activity).

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, it is difficult to Guess where is an Error, but you may try below code:

```
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


    Context mContext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Set your Alert Dialog box code
        mContext=this;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setMessage("This is Alert dialog messgae")
        .setTitle("Launch the date Picker")
        .setPositiveButton("Date Pick", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Launch a date picker from Here
                showDatePickerDialog();

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("cancel", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Cancel the Dialog itself  

            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }


    public void showDatePickerDialog() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    private static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), year, month, day);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

As you can see, I am creating a Date Picker using Fragment on click of Alert Dialog Button.

Your Activity needs to implement

> onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth)

Otherwise App crashes with an `java.lang.ClassCastException` with below error message :

```
MainActivity$DatePickerFragment cannot be cast to android.app.DatePickerDialog$OnDateSetListener
```

Answer (score 0):

AlertDialog is just for alert messages.  Use [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) and you can set your own content view.