# Hide month and year selection in datepicker dialog

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-datepicker

Hi I am passing month and year in datepicker dialog to show dates of that month is there any possible way to hide year and month from datepicker dialog[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5S7l.jpg)

This is what i need to show:
[image: This is what i need to show]

Comment: may [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10637343/3251783) help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide Year field in Android DatePicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401915/hide-year-field-in-android-datepicker)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MaterialDatePicker` provided by the Material Components Library.

Instead of hiding the month/year selector you can restrict the selection to a single month with a `CalendarConstraints`.

```
    long today = MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds();
    Calendar utc = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    utc.clear();
    utc.setTimeInMillis(today);
    utc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    long thisMonthFirst = utc.getTimeInMillis();
    utc.set(Calendar.DATE, utc.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
    long thisMonthLast = utc.getTimeInMillis();

    MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
    builder.setSelection(today);

    CalendarConstraints.Builder constraintsBuilder = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
    constraintsBuilder.setOpenAt(today);
    constraintsBuilder.setStart(thisMonthFirst);
    constraintsBuilder.setEnd(thisMonthLast);

    builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build());
    MaterialDatePicker<Long> picker = builder.build();
    picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), picker.toString());
```

In this way the selection is restricted to the current month and the user can't select another year/month.
You can change your logic (`utc.setTimeInMillis(today)`) to use another month.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`CalendarView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView) widget. Note that the year and month will be shown but not in big font. You can put it in a DialogFragment with a few buttons to achieve the result you want:

```java
public class CalendarViewDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";

    private long date = System.currentTimeMillis();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Context context = requireContext();

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null && args.containsKey(KEY_DATE)) {
            date = args.getLong(KEY_DATE);
        }

        CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(context);
        calendarView.setDate(date);
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener((view, year, month, dayOfMonth) ->
                date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth).getTimeInMillis());

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(calendarView)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, (dialog, which) -> {
                    if (getParentFragment() instanceof Callback) {
                        ((Callback) requireParentFragment()).onDateSelected(date);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                .create();
    }

    public static CalendarViewDialog newInstance(long date) {
        CalendarViewDialog dialog = new CalendarViewDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putLong(KEY_DATE, date);
        dialog.setArguments(args);
        return dialog;
    }

    public interface Callback {
        void onDateSelected(long date);
    }
}
```

Use it like this from another fragment:

```java
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements CalendarViewDialog.Callback {

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            CalendarViewDialog.newInstance(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .show(getChildFragmentManager(), "date-dialog");
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSelected(long date) {
        // Do whatever you want with `date`.
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes please @Nicolas

Comment: Java or Kotlin?

Comment: I need in JAVA Thanks in Advance

Comment: See my edit. Note that the year and month *will* be visible, but not in big font like with DatePickerDialog.