# Is there a way to hide top year picker in DatePicker?

Tags: android, datepicker

I wanted to only display the calendar part from the DatePicker dialog. Is there a way to hide the highlighted region in blue?

[image]

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233760/remove-year-from-datepickerdialog

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

XML:

```
<DatePicker
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            android:spinnersShown="false"/>
```